# Subset a dataframe with a loop

Tags: r, loops

I would like to subset a dataframe (Springs) by year with a loop and rename that dataset with the year.

```
Year.df <- matrix(nrow = 38, ncol = 1)
Year.df[,1] <- 1982:2019

for(i in 1:38){
Springs.Year.df[i,1] <- subset(Springs, DayNum <= 43 & BookYear == Year.df[i,1])
}
```

I get:

> Error: object 'Springs.Year.df' not found.

Comment: You can use  dput(Springs[38, ])  function to make a reproducible example. Btw, the 'Error: object 'Springs.Year.df' not found.' occurs because there is no object declared as 'Springs.Year.df' in the enviroment.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If you had provided an example of `Springs` dataset it would be easier to solve your issue.
If I correctly understanded `Spring` dataset structure, You can use `dplyr` package instead, It easily filters your dataset, Also for `subset` function, you don't need to do `for loop`.
But if you want to use a `for loop` in `baseR` code, you should loop through `Springs` dataset, not `Year.df`.
The following code covers all.(`dplyr`, `subset` and `for lool`)

```
library(dplyr)

Year.df <- matrix(nrow = 38, ncol = 1)
Year.df[,1] <- 1982:2019

# Creating an example dataset
Springs <- data.frame(
  DayNum = sample(10:100, 1000, replace = TRUE),
  BookYear = sample(1975:2021, 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

##------------------------------------------------
## dplyr, filter method
##------------------------------------------------  
Springs.Year.df <- Springs %>%
  filter(DayNum <= 43 & BookYear %in% Year.df)

#Result:

head(Springs.Year.df)
##   DayNum BookYear
## 1     31     2010
## 2     25     1982
## 3     29     1987
## 4     23     1985
## 5     17     1999
## 6     23     2005

nrow(Springs.Year.df)
## [1] 256



##-------------------------------------------------------------
## Subset method
##-------------------------------------------------------------

Springs.Year.df <- subset(Springs, DayNum <= 43 & BookYear %in% Year.df)


#Check the Result
head(Springs.Year.df)
##   DayNum BookYear
## 5     31     2010
## 7     25     1982
## 8     29     1987
## 17    23     1985
## 18    17     1999
## 22    23     2005

nrow(Springs.Year.df)
## [1] 256


##------------------------------------------------
## For loop method
##------------------------------------------------
Springs.Year.df <- data.frame()
#for loop for subsetting
for(i in 1:(nrow(Springs))){
  Day = ifelse(Springs$DayNum[i] <= 43, Springs$DayNum[i], "None")
  Year = ifelse(Springs$BookYear[i] %in% Year.df, Springs$BookYear[i], "None")
  if(Day != "None" & Year != "None"){
  to_add <- data.frame(DayNum = Day, BookYear = Year)
  Springs.Year.df <- rbind(to_add, Springs.Year.df)
  }
}


#Check the Result
head(Springs.Year.df)
##   DayNum BookYear
## 1     37     2018
## 2     41     2018
## 3     22     2013
## 4     35     2015
## 5     35     2007
## 6     23     2005
nrow(Springs.Year.df)
## [1] 256
```